# Converting Alamofire Multipart method to previous to latest 4.0 version , causes issue in multiform part data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I m posting a video to youtube using alamofire post request in mutliform part.With alamofire previous version my code was working fine,but on changing to updated version and running with `Swift3.0`, i m getting error

working code is :

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4")
 let videodata: Data = Data.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)! as! Data

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
       multipartFormData.append(path, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")},
        to: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    }
    )
```

Can anyone please help me to convert it to **Alamofire 4.0.1 version with Swift 3.0**

The error i m getting is : Expression type () is ambiguous without more context  --in this line : Alamofire.upload(

Comment: Whats the error, post the error log and which line causing it

Comment: @Tj3n please check the error

Comment: Your code have no problem, you are missing a bracket somewhere in the code, check for missing `}` or `)`

Comment: @Tj3n i have checked for all parantheses. Nothing seems to be missing

Comment: It work fine when i copy the whole `Alamofire.upload` into my project

Comment: @Tj3n still the same issue is there for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles in Swift 3.0:

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4")!
    let url = URL(string: path)!

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
    {   multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(url, withName:  "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")

    },
    to: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id",
    encodingCompletion:
    {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
```

By the way, why are you creating the **videodata** object if you don't use it it the upload code?

Comment: i m passing videodata in place of url,{multipartFormData.append(path, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")},